# Pass variable from controller to another in Symfony?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, doctrine, twig

I have 2 actions functions in my controller and I want to pass  variable to an other action function

This is my first function in my controller

```
public function newUserAction(Request $request)
{ ......... 
$url = $this->generateUrl('userBundle_new_user_reasonCodeAjaxView',  
array('id' => $newUser->getCode(),
            'countCode' => $countCode,));
            return $this->redirect($url);
```

This my second funtion in my controller

```
     public function userCodeAjaxViewAction(Request $request, $id)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pc = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:Code')->find($id);

    if($pc != null)
    {
        return $this->render('UserBundle:userCodeView.html.twig', array(
         'pc' => $pc,

        ));
    }
```

And my twif looks like this

```
    <div class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default step3-textarea top-arrow top-arrow">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <fieldset>
                 <div>
                    {{ pc.name|trans }}

     {{countCode}} 

                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting an error `Variable "countCode" does not exist in...`

Is there any idea how I can use a variable from a controller in a other controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get a variable from another controller.
Every request creates only one controller instance.

What you can do is create a Service that you can call in the controller.
Something like that:

```
class CountUserService{
    public function count(){
        return 1; // count users here
    }
}
```

And the in the controller do this:

```
$service = new CountUserService();
$data=['countCode' => $service->count()];
return $this->render('UserBundle:userCodeView.html.twig', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same template scope for the two controllers, and this is not possible. If you are using two controllers to render two simple informations, why not simply returning a JSON and displaying it in a more global template using AJAX ?

Else a pure symfony solution would be to have a main template `view.html.twig` where you would put

```
<div class="">
<div class="panel panel-default step3-textarea top-arrow top-arrow">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <fieldset>
             <div>
                {{ render(controller("AppBundle:UserController:newUserAction")) }}

                {{ render(controller("AppBundle:UserController:userCodeAjaxViewAction")) }}

            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</div>
```

Given that then your two controller action templates would be simple `{{ pc.name|trans }}` and `{{countCode}}`.

Hope it helps you out !

Comment: You could also make http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/index.html to solve this !